# Angular: Break up a page with it's own controller

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

**Given**

Absolute Newbie to Angular who wants to use the concept of "composition" where Main page contains lots of small web page parts.

I started out by creating just a Header section as shown below which binds perfectly.

```
<html>
<body >
    <div class="row" ng-app="HeaderModule" ng-controller="HeaderController">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <h1 class="page-header">
                {{header.Title}}
            </h1>
            <ol class="breadcrumb">
                <li class="active">
                    <i class="fa fa-dashboard">Some Data Here</i>
                </li>
            </ol>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
<script src="../../lib/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
    angular.module('HeaderModule', [])
    .controller('HeaderController', ['$scope',
        function ($scope) {
            $scope.header = { "Title": "Pretty Good, We see the binding work if this page is alone, by itself" }
        }])
</script>
```

But Angular doesn't want mulitple ng-app declarations so, I removed the HTML and Body and the ng-app declarations for the header page.

```
<div class="row" ng-controller="HeaderController">
```

The main page which looks like this and runs fine without the header page.  The first Div declares the application as follows.

```
   <div id="wrapper" ng-app="TestResultsApp">
```

The JavaScript logic looks like this.

```
 angular.module('TestResultsApp', [])
        .controller('CardsController', ['$scope',
            function ($scope) {
                $scope.results = {
                    'FirstCard': '12',
                    'SecondCard': '3',
                    'ThirdCard': '5',
                    'CardsSummary': '20'
                }
            }
        ])
```

Now I want to add the Header page but if possible keep the controller logic there if possible.  Or I could also split the JavaScript to a file, but still want the reference to be made by the Header page (single responsibility principal)...

**What's best way to do this?**

*Here's what I've tried so far:*

Using HTML5 import (webcomponents) I've successfully pulled in the Header page but Angular can't find the controller logic there.  If I pull out the ng-app declaration in the header page I don't know how to create just a controller that get's "sucked up" into the main ng-app (application)...

Please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular will only auto-bootstrap the first `ng-app` it finds. After that, you need to manually bootstrap the `ng-app`s on the page.

For a working example, [see this Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/v1XJjq2gA7hvQ88j8Xoq?p=preview)

```
angular.module('app1', []).controller('ctrl1', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
  $scope.title  = 'This is app1 ctrl1';
}]);

angular.module('app2', []).controller('ctrl1', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
  $scope.title  = 'This is app2 ctrl1';
}]);

angular.module('app3', []).controller('ctrl3', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
  $scope.title  = 'This is app3 ctrl1 title';
  $scope.title3  = 'This is app3 ctrl1 title3';
}]);

angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById("app1"), ['app1']);
angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById("app2"), ['app2']);
angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById("app3"), ['app3']);
```

But really, its probably a better idea to stick to one `ng-app` and use Angular Controllers together with [Directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) and [Components](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component) to achieve what you want to do.

Comment: Just wondering why is it better to stick to one ng-app?  I can agree with that if I can find a way to keep the controller logic contained in each page that needs just that logic.  I did find another way this works too, just specifiy the other ng-apps as dependencies in main page.   angular.module('app1', ['app2']).controller(....

Comment: If it's a small app, it's just easier on memory usage and keeping your code in order.  I currently work on a very large corporate Angular website, and it runs 4 different apps, and sometimes trying to keep all that code in the specific apps becomes difficult, especially when they have to interact with each other (luckily, most of that interaction is via the api).

Answer (score 1):

Found your other question by random occurrence.  The problem is that you're instantiating two different apps.  You have `angular.module('TestResultsApp', [])` and `angular.module('HeaderModule', [])`.  You should use the same app for both pieces.  Where you first have your app substantiated, use `angular.module('TestResultsApp', [])`, and then in your controller use `angular.module('TestResultsApp').controller(...)`.  That will assign the controller to the appropriate app.  Notice the lack of brackets in the second one.  Whenever you add brackets, you're instantiating Angular again.

Comment: Thanks Chris, I asked question here again with more clarity.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, if you want a pattern wherein you're mixing together the html template for a component and its javascript, you might be better off looking at react and JSX.

That said, if you declare each of these elements as a directive or component, you can do something like

```
angular.module('myApp')   //note we're not declaring it here, just referencing it
.component('header', {
  controller: function() { /* controller here */ }
  template: '<div>{{$ctrl.foo}}</div>'
});
```

If you're using babel or have access to backticks, you can make a multiline string pretty easily, which looks pretty similar to what you want, it just puts the html template inside a string.

Then you just have to wrap everything together into a big file and provide an entry point.

Comment: Yes what I'm doing fits JSX perfectly.  However I'm already knee deep into Angular and want the angular binding.  I think Angular has the ability to do components too....